# Performance of executing multiple operations on spark RDD

Tags: apache-spark

I would like to know what will be the performance cost of performing set of operations one by one instead of cumulative.
Here is some code to represent these two scenarios:

**Scenario 1:**

```
val operations: List[Row => Boolean]
val rdd: RDD[Row]
val result: RDD[Boolean] = rdd.flatMap(row => operations.map(f => f(row)))
```

**Scenario 2**

```
val operations: List[Row => Boolean]
val rdd: RDD[Row]
val result: RDD[Boolean] = sc.union(operations.map(f => rdd.map(f)))
```

I know that second one is more expensive, but I have some reasons to prefer it and I would like to know how much expensive it is.

My operations quantity is somewhere between 10 and 100, RDD size is in milions or more.

Comment: by the looks of it scenario 1 seems to be the way to go

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to execute both on representative data and benchmark the results. Only then you can get an answer which accurately reflects real life performance.

While the first one might benefit from data being loaded only once, there many other factors in play, like:

- Length of the lineage (is data cached, shuffled).
- Input format, if lineage is re-executed from the source.
- Amount of memory allocated for each operation and GC configuration.
- Overall amount of data yielded from a single pass over operations.
- Cluster configuration.
- Downstream transformations.

The first scenario can result in longer GC pauses or GC related OOMs, increased spilling to disk, or poor resource utilization. The second approach enables higher granularity, especially with dynamic allocation.